# Getting error Field UCLASS is not a member of BAPIUCLASS while updating through JCo

Tags: java, bapi, jco

I am trying to update `UCLASS` field value using `BAPI_USER_CHANGE` through JCo, but getting below error:

> com.sap.conn.jco.JCoRuntimeException: Field UCLASS is not a member of BAPIUCLASS

Here is my code to set the value:

```java
    JCoStructure license = params.getStructure("UCLASS");
    license.setValue("UCLASS", changes.get(0).getCurrent());
    JCoStructure licenseX = params.getStructure("UCLASSX");
    licenseX.setValue("UCLASS", 'X');
```

Can you please tell me this comes under which Structure? tried also with `LOGONDATA` and `ADDRESS`?

Comment: `UCLASS` and `UCLASSX` are the names of two parameters of `BAPI_USER_CHANGE`, they are structures (of types `BAPIUCLASS` and `BAPIUCLASSX` respectively) which both contain many fields. The method `setValue` must be used to fill the value of each field of that structure, e.g. `license.setValue("LIC_TYPE","any value")` will set the field `LIC_TYPE` of the structured parameter `UCLASS`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logon with a SAP GUI and use transaction SE37 to display the parameters and structures of the RFM BAPI_USER_CHANGE.
The ABAP workbench offers forward navigation. So if you would like to see how this UCLASS structure looks like, go to the Import tab of the RFM BAPI_USER_CHANGE and double-click on the Associated Type BAPIUCLASS.

You are correctly getting the error message because there is no field with name UCLASS in the RFM parameter UCLASS (which is a `JCoStructure`).
Instead of this, `license.setValue("LIC_TYPE", "XY");` would be valid here, for example.

If you want to set another structure as a whole, you would have to use
`params.setValue("UCLASS", myJCoStructure);`.

Comment: Thanks again for the detailed response and making me understand. I tried with **LIC_TYPE**, it worked.